# How to change if/else statement to loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

I would like to change if/else statement to loops in a function that receives a string and return to a new string which is changed the vowel letters to the next letter after it.

```js
function changeVowels(str) {
        var alphabet = 'abefijopuvABEFIJOPUV';
        var strNew = ""
        for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
           for(var j = 0; j < alphabet.length; j++){
             if(str[i] === alphabet[j] && j%2 === 0){
               strNew += alphabet[j+1]
            }
          }
          if(str[i]==='a' || str[i]==='i' || str[i]==='u'||str[i]==='e' || str[i]==='o'){}
          else if(str[i]==='A' || str[i]==='I' || str[i]==='U'|| str[i]==='E' || str[i]==='O'){}
          else{
           strNew+=str[i]
          }
        }
        return strNew
      }

console.log(changeVowels('Car'))
```

how to change if/else statement below to loops ?

```
if(str[i]==='a' || str[i]==='i' || str[i]==='u'||str[i]==='e' || str[i]==='o'){}
else if(str[i]==='A' || str[i]==='I' || str[i]==='U'|| str[i]==='E' || str[i]==='O'){}
else{strNew+=str[i]}
```

or i don't mind you change it besides loop, or make it shorter

Comment: not sure how you can turn ANY `if`/`else` to a `loop` - the two things are two different programming constructs

Comment: And a loop is **really** not the way to handle it

Comment: `return str.split('').map(l => 'aeiou'.includes(l.toLowerCase()) ? String.fromCharCode(l.charCodeAt(0) + 1): l).join('');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need loops to simplify this code

Both `str[i]==='a' || str[i]==='i' || str[i]==='u'||str[i]==='e' || str[i]==='o'` and `str[i]==='A' || str[i]==='I' || str[i]==='U'|| str[i]==='E' || str[i]==='O'` are about the same letters but with different capitalisation, so you can reduce your code in half by only considering one case (upper or lower) and converting anything to that. If you extract `str[i]` as a variable, you can further reduce the repetition:

```
var char = str[i].toUpperCase();
/* ... */
if (char==='A' || char==='I' || char==='U'|| char==='E' || char==='O') {}
```

you can further reduce the multiple ORs if you use an array and [Array#includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) alternatively [String#includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) will do the same but I'll use an array since it's a bit more universal for values, even if a string would be shorter.

```
if (['A', 'I', 'U', 'E', 'O'].includes(char)) {
  /* code */
} else {
  strNew+=str[i];
}
```

and if you want to do nothing in the first case, you can further just eliminate the `else` by inverting the condition:

```
if (!['A', 'I', 'U', 'E', 'O'].includes(char)) {
//  ^ invert the result
  strNew+=str[i];
}
```

Comment: strings also have 'includes' method

Comment: @JaromandaX yeah, I just added a note for why I used an array. basically, more universal, you can also use it for numbers, for example.

Answer (score 2):

You could check if the character is a vowel and then take the next letter from a given string or the actual letter.

```js
function changeVowels(str) {
  var alphabet = 'abefijopuvABEFIJOPUV';
  var strNew = ""
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if ('aeiou'.includes(str[i].toLowerCase())) {
      strNew += alphabet[alphabet.indexOf(str[i]) + 1];
    } else {
      strNew += str[i];
    }
  }
  return strNew;
}

console.log(changeVowels('Car'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another fun way to do it

```js
function changeVowels(str) {
    var x = {a:'b', e:'f', i:'j', o: 'p', u: 'v', A: 'B', E: 'F', I: 'J', O: 'P', U: 'V'};
    return str.split('').map(l => x[l] || l).join('');
}
console.log(changeVowels('Car'))
```

Or if you really want that `alphabet` var

```js
function changeVowels(str) {
    var alphabet = 'abefijopuvABEFIJOPUV';
    var x = Object.fromEntries(alphabet.match(/../g).map(kv => kv.split('')));
    return str.split('').map(l => x[l] || l).join('');
}
console.log(changeVowels('Car'))
```

Explanation of `var x = Object.fromEntries(alphabet.match(/../g).map(kv => kv.split('')));`

`alphabet.match(/../g)` produces an array `['ab', 'ef', 'ij', ... etc]`

`.map(kv => kv.split(''))` maps the above to `[['a', 'b'], ['e', 'f'], ... etc`

`Object.fromEntries([['a', 'b'], ['e', 'f'] .... etc])` produces

```
{
    a: 'b',
    e: 'f',
    i: 'j',
    o: 'p',
    u: 'v',
    A: 'B',
    E: 'F',
    I: 'J',
    O: 'P',
    U: 'V'
};
```

same as the first snippet

Answer (score 0):

I will make it simpler for you

```js
function changeVowels(str) {
        var alphabet = 'abefijopuvABEFIJOPUV';
        for(var i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++){
           str = str.replace(new RegExp(alphabet[i], 'g'), alphabet[i+1]);
           i++
        }
        return str
}

console.log(changeVowels('Facebook'))
```

Answer (score -1):

separate your string and check if that exist in your alphabet variable. if it present means u get the next character or else return the same character and so on

```js
var alphabet = 'abefijopuvABEFIJOPUV';

function changeVowels(str) {
const newArray = str.split('').map(element => {
  let index = alphabet.indexOf(element);
  if(index > -1) {
return alphabet.charAt(index + 1);
  } else {
return element;
  }
})
return newArray.join('');
}

console.log('final ---  ', changeVowels('Car'))
```